# Get Time is not allowed to be called from a MonoBehaviour constructor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm writing a **"dash system"** in the Unity. And this sytem have a **cooldown**. And cooldown code is giving an error. My characterMovement script is here:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Normal Movement
    public Vector3 vel;
    public float speed;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    private bool isGrounded;
    public int level; // I don't use this variable
    //Dash
    public float DashPower; 
    public Vector3 DashVel;
    private float DashCooldown;

    void Awake(){
        speed = 3.25f;
        DashPower = 8f;
        DashCooldown = Time.time + 5.55f; 
    }
    void OnCollisionStay(){
        isGrounded = true;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        vel = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"),0f,Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        transform.position += vel * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        DashVel = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"),0f,Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded){
            rb.AddForce(new Vector3(0f,1.25f,0f) * 5, ForceMode.Impulse);
            isGrounded = false;
        }
        if(Time.time >= DashCooldown){        
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q)){
                transform.position += DashVel * DashPower * Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my code giving this error: [O](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtUpZ.png)
PlayerMovement.cs:12 = public Rigidbody rb;

Answer (score 2):

I checked your script, and does not throw the compilation error you mention.
Make sure that at the time you **save** your scripts and compile, you dont have any initialization logic in the variable declaration.
At the class construction time, the compiler expects constant values in the variables, that is why you cannot for example set the array length with a variable at the point of variable declaration.
I believe this has to do with the fact that a field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'name' in c#. You can check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0236) for better understanding.

For example this lines also throws the compilation error you mention, because you trying to set the variable with logic at declare time.

`private Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);`

Check [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/get_main-is-not-allowed-to-be-called-from-a-monobehaviour-constructor.452420/), where I got the line that throws the error example and checked it actually does throw the error.

On the other hand, nothing to do with the problem but you can do the `rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();` in the `Start()` or the `Awake()` instead of the `Update()`, as you just need to keep the reference to have it available within the class that is better that search for each every frame in the `Update()`.